# Blender: Bones get enlarged in export/import process

Tags: blender, export, import, bones

I have a rig in blender that I want to export into a different blender project. For some reason, when I do that, some of the bones get enlarged. All the scales are applied. Why might this be happening?

I've no clue why this might be happening, as this problem seems exclusive to this project and one other project, where one bone out of the whole armature gets enlarges, but here is the information I can provide:

Some differences between the projects where this happens and the others is that the ones where this does happen have animations, and a pose library. However, this does not seem to cause the problem, as deleting the animations and poses doesn't change anything.

This problem happens when I export/import the project as an FBX.

I usually export the project to unity and in order to compensate for the unity/blender rotation, I follow this [guide][1. I rotate the armature -90 on the x axis, apply rotation. Then rotate the armature 90 on the x axis but only apply the rotation to the mesh. I export the project as a FBX, with unity unit scale, no leaf bones, and the 3rd and 4th box under animations checked off. This also does not seem to cause the problem, as not rotating the armature and such doe not change anything.

Comment: Did you mean to ask this in [the Blender StackExchange](https://blender.stackexchange.com/)?

Comment: No, I already put this question up on Blender StackExchange and Blender Artists a few days ago and I'm not getting any response so I put the question here to see if anyone knows the answer.

Comment: When you're not attracting the answers you need, a good way to solve that is to add details to your question. Walk us through every step we need to follow to reproduce this problem, including creating both the source and destination projects. Once we're able to replicate exactly the problem you're facing, we can test solutions to be sure they'll work for you, without having to guess.

Comment: I can only guess it is something with import/export settings. Did you try different formats? Using gltf comes to mind.